# Cannot allow user to connect after allowing his IP through INBOUND rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I whitelisted an IP address on EC2 and the site is still prompting username and password, because it's setup so that the browser request the username and password before the page even loads. I am not sure what inside the EC2 instance is doing this, because I didn't set it up though.

I whitelisted an IP by selecting HTML, port 80 and the IP address of the user inside the security group section. I modified the security group being applied to the EC2 instance, but not the web page itself, and I Whitelisted the IP inside the php config of the website, so I am wondering if there's something else that might be blocking someone's IP. What that might be? What are the possibilities and how do you investigate this?

Did I correctly set it up? Like I said, I selected HTML, port 50 and entered his IP address and added /32 at the end, so I am wondering if there's anything else that needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is needed for the traffic to reach your EC2 instance. And being prompted for a username/password means that what you did is working.

On the other hand, you need to find where the credentials are being managed so you can create a username/password for your user to be able to access the service.